# C# Regex to match Url folder pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have an application which needs to find and then process Urls which follow a pattern like this:
`http://www.actuino.fr/projets/frankenblink
 http://www.actuino.fr/projets/
 http://www.actuino.fr/projets`

I have the following pattern which almost works...

```
string pattern = @"http://www.actuino.fr/projets/?.*";
```

Unfortunately that pattern will grab all Urls with 'projets' in as like this

`http://www.actuino.fr/projetsarduino
 http://www.actuino.fr/projets_rasberry`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundary.

```
string pattern = @"http://www\.actuino\.fr/projets\b/?.*";
```

or

Positive lookahead Assertion.

```
string pattern = @"(?m)http://www\.actuino\.fr/projets(?=/|$)/?.*";
```

`(?=/|$)` asserts that the previous token `projects` must be followed by a `/` or end of the line.

Comment: It' OK with word boundary. 
KO with Positive lookahead Assertion.`http://www.actuino.fr/projets` will not grab.

Comment: It's OK. Can you explain this Positive lookahead Assertion regex?